# R Propensity score matching with million row data

Tags: r, matching, propensity-score-matching

I ran PMS (nearest) using MatchIt package with 2 million row data.
However, it took more than a day and was not stopped normally.

Is there any substitution methods that can handle PMS with large data?

Hopefully.. somebody knows.

Comment: You could try the `Matching` package.

Comment: Why don't you try PS subclassification? It is much faster and often performs as well or better than matching. The `MatchIt` documentation has lots of details about how to do it.

Comment: You can also try adding exact matching constraints (i.e., using the `exact` argument). This will both improve the quality of the matches and make it run much faster. Make sure you set `verbose = TRUE` to see how much progress has been made.